# comparing different values of two arrays and returning one filtered array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare the values of two different arrays, if the **user.id** of the volunteer iteration matches the **id** of the **userVolunteer** iteration, I want that entry to be filtered out of the volunteers array

**current attempt:**

```
  const newBirds = volunteers.filter((volunteer) => {
    return volunteer.user_id !== userVolunteers.some((vol) => vol.id)
  });
```

newBirds currents returns the volunteers array without filtering any of the entries? Any advice?

Comment: `.some()` returns a boolean, which you probably don't want to compare to your ID

Comment: using .map yields the same results

Comment: So, you want to basically just filter out any element of the `volunteers` array that matches the ID of any element of the `userVolunteers` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the logic of comparison *inside* the `some` callback:

```
const newBirds = volunteers.filter((volunteer) => {
  return userVolunteers.some((vol) => volunteer.user_id !== vol.id)
});
```

Comment: Amazing stuff! Thanks!